# Firefox MIME sniffing cyrillic extensions

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

Consider an example piece of code below

```
function download(text) {
    var pom = document.createElement('a');
    pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    pom.setAttribute('download', 'test.тест');
   pom.click();
}
```

As you can see the file extension in the download attribute is in cyrillic. Apparently when Firefox encounters a generic application mime type it takes the extension and displays it as the type, but doing so with a cyrillic extension it displays it mangled by the wrong encoding.
[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkNUL.png)

If I remove the extension from download attribute completely, it displays the type as octet-stream, but unfortunately it is necessary that the extension is retained for usability purposes. Does anyone know of a way to work around this behaviour so that it either displays the extension correctly or just shows the supplied mime type instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a browser bug, and we fixed it [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1719598).